# Difference between multiple columns within a single dataframe

Tags: r

I am looking at a simple way to do the difference between multiple columns within a single dataframe and get the results within the same dataframe. Here is a reproducible example where I would like to subtract var1 from var1.bis, var2 for var2.bis, etc.

```
df1 <- data.frame(var1 = sample(1:10),
                  var2 = sample(1:10),
                  var3 = sample(1:10),
                  var1.bis = sample(1:10),
                  var2.bis = sample(1:10),
                  var3.bis = sample(1:10))
```

Comment: What about `dplyr::mutate()`?

Comment: Just `df1[, 7:9] <- df1[,4:6] - df1[,1:3]` ?

Comment: omg why I complicated everything with a loop... Sorry, I will delete. And thanks !!

Comment: @ePoQ don't delete the question, it could be useful for others (and I would like to see a tidyverse solution that actually depends on the name of the columns)

Comment: Like this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63988742/how-to-use-mutate-at-with-two-sets-of-variables-in-r/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider subtracting blocks of variables like two matrices using `grep` for pattern matching on `colnames`. You can even assign result as new columns:

```
bis_cols <- grep("\\.bis", colnames(df1), invert=FALSE)
non_bis_cols <- grep("\\.bis", colnames(df1), invert=TRUE)

df1[paste0("var_diff_", non_bis_cols)] <- df1[,bis_cols] - df1[,non_bis_cols]
```

<kbd>[**Online Demo**](https://rextester.com/ZGVI27020)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks, can you also add the simple solution as discussed in the comments : df1[, 7:9] <- df1[,4:6] - df1[,1:3]. I will then validate your answer.

Comment: That's exactly what `grep` does! It returns numbered indexes. This solution does not rely on numbered orders of columns. Give it a try. I add online demo link.

Comment: And that's quite a good solution, but if someone has different colnames like `LETTERS[1:6]`, the grep solution doesn't work

Comment: Correct, then adjust the pattern (`\\.bis`) accordingly such as `paste(LETTERS[1:6], collapse="|")`. The pattern in `grep` must be tailored to `colnames`. In fact, `invert` is only used here for your example.